# Part of layer cut/disappears after exporting to pdf in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pdf, print-composer

This is driving me crazy. The picture says it all:

[image]

You can see whole layer in QGIS browser and Composer, but when i export to pdf some layers are cut. I have tried moving the cut layers to the top of a layer tree, tried disabling labeling, tried to export them one by one, tried exporting to image and every time the result is same. 
This somehow happens to only a few random layers. 
Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you have a rotation set for your map?

Comment: Are the disappearing layers WMS-layers? If so, they might sometimes required large images then the WMS server is willing to supply. If this is the case, try re-adding the WMS layer but set a small enough tile size (512x512) and instead print composer will request the data from that server in smaller chunks to build a large image.

Comment: Yes @ndawson, just played a bit more with settings and came back to post that the problem disappear when i set the rotation to zero. Is it possible to keep all the parts of my layers AND rotation? The layers are not WMS, although i also have a few of those on

Comment: Sounds like this bug: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9691

Comment: Yup, Thank You ndawson.To anyone who will run into such problem just change the layer transparency to 0.

Comment: @TimCouwelier how can I change the tile size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug - http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9691 . You can work around it by either setting the map's rotation to 0 or by removing the layer transparency.