# QGIS export to PDF layer is disappearing

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, export, pdf

I would like to reopen/look again at this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95974/part-of-layer-cut-disappears-after-exporting-to-pdf-in-qgis). I have a aerial raster file with a vector file over the top indicating specific points on the ground. I created my map, set the rotation to zero, not using WMS-layers, toggled the transparency, exported multiple times; the output PDF file continues to loose written data. The raster looks good, but the shapefile only shows up on the top half.

Has anyone else ran into this problem?

**QGIS raster background with red points.**
[image]

**Exported Geo-referenced PDF**

[image]

Comment: I just tried printing a geospatial PDF, using QGIS 3.14.1-Pi. the data sources were an ECW and Geopackage layer, I wasn't able to replicate the problem...…. Can you try saving your shapefile data as a geopackage layer? The problem almost seems to be that the PDF printing can't access the shapefile data fast enough.

Comment: I tried using the Geopackage layer, but it did not work. Same output. I also tried using a clipped and compressed version of my raster since the original is just over 10GB. I've had similar problems before sometimes and just have either tried again or restarted QGIS. None of these methods have worked yet.

Comment: I tried exported without Geo-referencing and that worked. However, I do need a geo-referenced map.

Comment: Could it be the coordinate system? maybe the PDF geo-referencing process doesn't understand your coordinate system, maybe try with a generic coord system?

Comment: I am using WGS84 UTM 10. I ran it again late yesterday and it worked just fine. The only problem was that there was a faint line, like a frame, around my map. Though the frame option was not checked. I've had troubles with QGIS running out of memory/not processing correctly unless you restart the program. Perhaps that was the issue???

Comment: Yes the way that the black dots 'stop' on your printing doesn't look like a 'map extent' issue, but rather it getting to a point where it just stops printing. Im wondering if the complexity of the style contributes to the application running out of memory also? (maybe make the dots filled and single colour).

Comment: I have tried using filled and single color vs. transparent. Same problem. Weird....

Comment: dammit - I HATE it when a problem resolves itself and I don't know why. but happy you got it working at least.

Comment: I'll post back here is I ever find out why that is happening!

Comment: @nr_aus Hey, I ended up finding a solution. Though like we discussed before, I have no idea why it works. Any ideas?

Comment: saw your answer below - Opacity hey. hmmm. is that the opacity on the raster layer im assuming?

Comment: It's the opacity of the entire map. So the raster layer with the shapefile above. There is a warning box that appears talking about `Composition Effects`. I updated my answer with a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After coming back to this problem, I was able to determine a cause, though I am not sure why. In the map properties I adjusted the Opacity to 50% and saved, it worked. A box will appear letting you know there will be some composition effects. I do not believe this causes any issues with GeoReferencing, but I could be wrong. I then changed back to 100% and it worked. I hope this will help someone else in the future!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interesting....